# Создание csv с помощью csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, csv

при создании csv файла заходит дикт c двумя полями. Например Field1 and field2

field1 = может содержать до 3000 символов. В нем есть различные знаки "@$@%!^*(!"|_*(*(*))_ - например.
field2 = может содержать до 100 символов.

проблема в том, что при создании csv field заварачивается в кавычки = "field1"
можно ли как то это убрать.

"" - нет в строке питона.

Допустим заходит такой дикт

```
abs = {
'field1' : 'dgksdgksd;leitit3twflcm,vxc3950-2323erw[er[kcxcxzc',
'field2' : 'sdasdasdasdasdsadas'
}
```

создаю csv таким кодом

```
columns = ['field1', 'field2']
csv_file = 'test.csv'
with open(csv_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig' ) as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns, delimiter='}')
    writer.writeheader()
    for dataload in data_csv:
        writer.writerow(dataload)
```

а на выходе получаю csv файл

```
field1}field2

"dgksdgksd;leitit3twflcm,vxc3950-2323erw[er[kcxcxzc"}sdasdasdasdasdsadas
```

как исбавиться от этих ковычек

Comment: Я запустил ваш код и у меня нет кавычек: `dgksdgksd;leitit3twflcm,vxc3950-2323erw[er[kcxcxzc}sdasdasdasdasdsadas`. Мб, у вас в строке они есть? Какая у вас версия питона? Еще можно попробовать в `DictWriter` указывать `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL`: `writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=columns, delimiter='}', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)`.

Comment: версия 3.7
в принте выводится строка 

'dgksdgksd;leitit3twflcm,vxc3950-2323erw[er[kcxcxzc'

Comment: в строке могут быть " - то есть в самой строке может быть " и не один

Comment: Поэтому и добавляется `"`, а внутри строки добавляется экранирование `"`, например `\"`. т.е. если не хотите чтобы были кавычки вокруг полей, то нужно выбрать другой символ для экранирования, например `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar=" "`, тогда пробел добавится перед кавычкой внутри строки-поля. Либо, не используйте `csv.DictWriter`, а вручную сгенерируйте файл с нужным вам разделителем